# Start the correct python program via symbolic link

Tags: python, symlink, activepython

I recently installed ActivePython 2.7. So I've got a symbolic link in */usr/local/bin/python* which points to the 2.7 directory. Trouble is, when I type "python" at the command line, it starts up MacPython 2.6 in */usr/bin/python*. I don't understand why the symbolic link is not taking precedence. */usr/local/bin* is on my PATH. Any help would be appreciated.

```
~ $ which python
/usr/bin/python

~ $ find /usr -iname python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Path looks like this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/PalmPDK/bin:/opt/PalmSDK/Current/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you type “python” on the command line, the shell checks the values in your $PATH from left to right, and invokes the program it finds first. Check your current $PATH setting like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

If it contains both /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin then whichever comes first will take precedence.

Comment: ah-ha! I thought the later ones would take precedence. stupid. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in your PATH variable, /usr/bin probabbly is before the /usr/local/bin/ directory. you should use the full path in order to work in this case.